# Special characters display with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, character-encoding, character

I have declared the encoding at the beginning of my file :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

I have this list of words which have special characters

```
wordswithspecialcharacters =  "hors-d'œuvre régal bétail œil écœuré hameçon ex-æquo niño".split()
```

When I use a function to manipulate those words and print them, the characters are fine :

```
def plusS (word) :
    word = word+"s"
    return word

for x in range (len(wordswithspecialcharacters)) :
    print wordswithspecialcharacters[x]
```

this will print them correctly.

But if I simply print the list wordswithspecialcharacters  I get:

> ["hors-d'\xc5\x93uvre", 'r\xc3\xa9gal', 'b\xc3\xa9tail', '\xc5\x93il',
>   '\xc3\xa9c\xc5\x93ur\xc3\xa9', 'hame\xc3\xa7on', 'ex-\xc3\xa6quo',
>   'ni\xc3\xb1o']

My questions:

1. Why doesn't it display them correctly in the list?
2. How could I fix that issue?

Thanks

Comment: 1. It uses `repr()` on the items in the list. 2. Use Python 3.

Comment: @ekhumoro : is there any way to fix it with Python 2.7?

Comment: 1. if you print a list you will always get an escaped display of the strings inside. 2. strings containing unicode should be marked with a `u` (→ `u"hors-d'œuvre régal..."`) in Python 2,

Comment: @JonathP. `print repr(words).decode('string-escape')`.